# NGINX rewrites for Yoast SEO Sitemaps on multiple wordpress subdirectories

Tags: wordpress, nginx, url-rewriting, yoast

According to [this blog post](https://kb.yoast.com/kb/xml-sitemaps-nginx/), it's bad if https://example.com/blog/?sitemap=1 works.

That's a wordpress installation in a subdirectory.

Yoast advises at that post to use this rewrite:

```
# Rewrites for Yoast SEO XML Sitemap
rewrite ^/sitemap_index.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=1 last;
rewrite ^/([^/]+?)-sitemap([0-9]+)?.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=$1&sitemap_n=$2 last;
```

This won't work because my wordpress installs (3 on the same server) are each in subdirectories.

How can I get two lines of nginx config which works even for multiple sites in subdirectories?

Further, it didn't work even for the one subsite when I tried the following:

```
rewrite ^/blog/sitemap_index.xml$ /blog/index.php?sitemap=1 last;
rewrite ^/blog/([^/]+?)-sitemap([0-9]+)?.xml$ /blog/index.php?sitemap=$1&sitemap_n=$2 last;
```

As ?sitemap=1 still works.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I generalize this for multiple subsites?

Comment: Where in your NGINX configs were you placing these lines?

Comment: @CollinM.Barrett It was in the location \@wordpress, right before rewrites for /blog/ to /blog/index.php, /blog2/ /blog2/index.php